# How to look up Language ID of messages?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do you look up a list of language IDs available within SQL Server?

I am specifically looking if there are any views within `sys` schema.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from syslanguages
```

The id is a Locale ID language code as defined by Microsoft. A list of them can also be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221435).

Comment: Thanks, Adrian.  Actually I had to add "sys." schema in front of syslanguages like "select * from sys.syslanguages".  But thank you for pointing me the right direction.  Haven't thought of prepending languages with "sys"...

Comment: Yes, the `syslanguages` view is in the `sys` schema so you can do `select * from sys.syslanguages`. My default login uses this schema, hence I didn't need the `sys.` prefix.